# Where is the ISO file to burn image to CD

Tags: iso, cd

I have installed `InfraRecorder` and it says to burn the `.iso` image.  I am by far NOT computer literate and I don't know what an `.iso` file is.  Am I suppose to download the entire application to the computer and then onto the `CD`.  I was trying to avoid putting the entire file on my computer.

How do you burn from internet Ubuntu page onto the disc.  Thank you for any answers.

Comment: Are you asking how to create a CD you can use to install Ubuntu 12.04? Are you currently using Windows?

Comment: Look at this page for general instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto Whether you are using Windows or Linux you need to download the entire .iso. Once you have succesfully used it you could always delete it...

Comment: Sorry didn't got your question 
you mean how to burn is using infrarecorder or burn is without downloading iso?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you will have to download the entire file ; most CD burner programs will not burn a disk from a file on the internet, and even if they would, unless your connection is very fast, and very stable, you'd probably end up with a bad CD anyway.

Other ways to get a bootable copy of Ubuntu would include purchasing the [8GB Mini USB with Ubuntu Precise](http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=1000) (sadly, not available yet).